# Determinant of all possible matrices with elements $\pm 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given that A is an element of set $\mathbb{B}$ consisting of all $N\times N$ matrices with elements $\pm 1$, how can I find the following sum:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{A\in \mathbb{B}} \det(A) 
\end{equation}
My initial approach was to use elementary row operations to reduce the matrix to the following form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & A^{N-1}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $A^{N-1}$ consists of elements $\{-2,0,2\}$. Since each row has those elements, we can divide each row to 2. That will reduce the determinant to $2^{N-1}A'$. But the road ended here. My insight is that, as we have $\pm 1$ for each element, determinants should cancel out and give $0$.

Comment: Note that $\det(-A)=-\det(A)$ if and only if $N$ is odd ([see proof here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393692/why-is-det-a-1n-deta)), so the sum is indeed equal to $0$ if $N$ is odd, otherwise it might be a different value.

Comment: Only flip one row, not the whole matrix

Comment: Didn't understand what you meant by flipping one row but not the whole matrix

Comment: It made more sense when there was another comment suggesting you pair up each $A$ with $-A$.  $Det(-A)=-Det(A)$ when $N$ is odd, so the sum of the two determinants is zero.  All matrices belong to one of these pairs, so the sum of all the determinants is zero.  I suggested flipping the sign of just one row, not the whole matrix, because it also works for even $N$.

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's define a map  $\varphi : \mathbb{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{B}$ such that for every $A \in \mathbb{B}$, you obtain $\varphi(A)$ by swapping the two first rows of $A$. It is obvious that $\varphi$ is a bijection (it is an involution), so
$$ \sum_{A \in \mathbb{B}} \det(A) =  \sum_{A \in \mathbb{B}} \det(\varphi(A))= - \sum_{A \in \mathbb{B}} \det(A)$$

So $$\boxed{ \sum_{A \in \mathbb{B}} \det(A)=0}$$

Comment: How can we say $\sum det(A)$ is equal to $\sum det(\phi(A))$

Comment: Because the set of all $\phi(A)$ includes all the same matrices, just in a different order.